# link a page in option tag value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to link a tag in option tag value.
select,sample and add is my option tag values.
If I click add option I want to link client.php page.
onChange="window.location.href=this.value" will open in same page as well as it will display page not found error for fetched value from database.

I affixed my code.

```
       echo '<select name="c" onChange="window.location.href=this.value" style="width:160px;">';
       echo '<option selected>select</option>';
       $op="select * from client";
       $op1=mysql_query($op); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($op1))
       {
        echo '<option  value='.$row["c_name"].'>'.$row["c_name"].'</option>';
       }
       echo '<option  value="/client.php">Add new client</option>';
       echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know if i understand what you need but if it was me i would just create a javascript function that would allow me to perform a custom action based on the option value tag, if it is an hyperlink or an option value. I was thinking on something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('c').onchange = function(){
          var test = (this.value.indexOf('/')===0) ? true : false;
          if(test)
          {
               window.location.href = this.value;
          }
     }
</script>
```

And on the php code you only have to change this:

```
 echo '<select name="c" id="c" style="width:160px;">';
```

Just tell me if it doesn't do what you need

Comment: It doesn't redirect to link.

Comment: Try the following, remove onChange="selectChanged()" and add id='c'  and swap your javascript for this one : 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('c').onchange = function () {   var test = (this.value.indexOf('/')===0) ? true : false;
          if(test)
          {
               window.location.href = this.value;
          }
  };
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Its because, you are not sending the current page url to it.

```
echo '<select name="c" onChange="window.location.href=this.value" style="width:160px;">';
```

Should be

```
echo '<select name="c" onChange="window.location.href=<?php echo $_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\'];?>&val=this.value" style="width:160px;">';
```

Where `val` is the drop down value.